# Can't run any generator on Yeoman

Tags: node.js, npm, generator, yeoman

When I run any generator installed on yeoman it always says that cannot find module (something)

For example:
I tried to run webapp and it appears this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'cross-spawn' 
>   ....

I run: `$ npm install cross-spawn -g`

then: `$ yo webapp`

and another error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'

Can anyone help me plz.

Comment: Try to `npm cache clean` then re-install the generator